# Save uploads directly in the uploads folder (on a multisite)

Tags: multisite, uploads

on my current page I want my uploads to be saved directly in the uploaded folder. So their links should be something like `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/myimage.jpg` instead of `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2018/09/myimage.jpg`.

I remember reading somewhere, that this can be set under Settings->Media. However, the option doesn't appear there on my installation.

[image]

I should probably mention that this is a multisite installation. So maybe the named option can be found somewhere else there. But I couldn't find it yet. Do you know where to find this setting or how to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now here is how you can disable it in WordPress Multi-sites:

- Login to Dashboard
- Go to *Network Admin*
- Go to *Sites* tab
- Click on *Edit* link for particular site.
- Toggle to 4 tab under it – *Settings*
- Look for ***"Uploads Use Yearmonth Folders"***
- Change the value in text field from **1** to **0**
- Save the settings.

Comment: Thank you, that is actually exactly what I was looking for!